# How to use the children: <Widget> of a Row to display a list of Icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am pretty new to Flutter development and I'm trying to pass a List to a Row using the `children : <Widget>[]` since I want to add something else beside the list in the future.

I know that this feature only accepts Widgets and maybe I have to convert my list to a Widget in someway ?

Any hints or tips on how to get it to work is appreciated :)

**This is working.**

```
List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];

Row(
  children: scoreKeeper,
),
```

**This is not.**

I get this error: **The element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.**

```
List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];

Row(
   children : <Widget>[
    scoreKeeper,
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the spread operator (...) from Dart 2.3 which will spread the list of, in this case, Icons and it will work.

```
List<Icon> scoreKeeper = [];

Row(
   children : <Widget>[
    ...scoreKeeper,
  ],
),
```